# Android Permission Used Time

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-package-managers

I have made a simple application that get all applications installed and permission requested by particular app using Package manager. I want to check when that app used its required permission last time.

I am stuck don't know what to do any hint how to check the time when app used internet or other permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no metrics tracked in the framework for this or a public API which provides this information.